# Why does my form need to be bigger than its containing panels to display them?

Tags: c#, winforms, size

I'm using simple code to generate a grid (gridSize * gridSize fields with lines dividing them in column and row, basically a TicTacToe grid).

As I'm creating the panels dynamically during Form_Load, I need to also adjust the size of the form. However, setting it to gridSize * tileSize, gridSize * tileSize is not big enough - I found by experimentation that I need to add ~15 to width and ~40 to height for gridSize = 3 and tileSize = 120. Why is this?

Code below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int tileSize = 120;
        const int gridSize = 3;

        /* Here: When setting size, I need to add 15 and 40? */
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(tileSize * gridSize + 15, tileSize * gridSize + 40);

        // initialize the "board"
        tictactoeFields = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize]; // column, row

        // double for loop to handle all rows and columns
        for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
        {
            for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
            {
                // create new Panel control which will be one 
                // tic tac toe field
                var newPanel = new Panel
                {
                    Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                    Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                };

                // add to our 2d array of panels for future use
                tictactoeFields[n, m] = newPanel;

                newPanel.BackColor = Color.White;

                if(n != 0)
                {
                    // Draw a line in front (to the left) of this panel
                    Panel leftSeparator = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(1, tileSize),
                        Location = newPanel.Location,
                        BackColor = Color.Black
                    };

                    Controls.Add(leftSeparator);
                }
                if(m != 0)
                {
                    // Draw a line on top (above) this panel
                    Panel topSeparator = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(tileSize, 1),
                        Location = newPanel.Location,
                        BackColor = Color.Black
                    };

                    Controls.Add(topSeparator);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(Panel pan in tictactoeFields)
        {
            // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
            Controls.Add(pan);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use ClientSize, not Size! The former is the inner net area, the latter the outer one, including borders and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Size` property is just a shorthand for setting the size of the [Bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) property which includes nonclient elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and menus.

What you should do is to set the size of the [ClientRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property, or use the `ClientSize` shorthand.

There's also a [DisplayRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property which includes padding, but in this case use the `ClientRectangle` property.

```
this.ClientSize = new Size((tileSize * gridSize), (tileSize * gridSize));
```

Comment: `DisplayArea` will also include the full size of a scrolled control.

Comment: Thanks to both for the solution and especially the explanation. Setting this.ClientSize instead of this.Size solved the problem